# Pytorch ddp timeout at inference time

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, distributed

Pytorch ddp timeout at inference time.
Here is part of my training/testing code:

```
def main(configs):
    _n_gpu = int(os.environ.get("WORLD_SIZE", 0))
    _global_rank = int(os.environ.get("RANK", 0))
    _local_rank = int(os.environ.get("LOCAL_RANK", 0))
    envs = {'RANK': _global_rank, 'LRANK': _local_rank, 'nGPU': _n_gpu}
    set_random_seed(configs.seed + _global_rank)
    device = torch.device(_local_rank)

    """ init model and DDP """
    os.environ["NCCL_BLOCKING_WAIT"] = "1"
    if train_idx == 0:
        dist.init_process_group(backend="nccl", init_method="env://", timeout=timedelta(seconds=900))

    model = setup_model(configs)
    model.to(device)
    optimizer = setup_e2e_optimizer(model, configs) 
    model = DistributedDataParallel(model, device_ids=([_local_rank] if configs.cpu != 1 else None), find_unused_parameters=True)

    """ init dataset """
    trainloader, test_loader = setup_dataloaders(configs)  # already initialized with dist sampler
    total_bs = _n_gpu * configs.train_batch_size
    configs.total_steps = int(math.ceil(1. * configs.num_train_epochs * len(trainloader.dataset) / total_bs))
    configs.val_steps = int(math.ceil(1. * configs.total_steps / configs.num_valid))

    """training start"""
    model.train()
    dist.barrier()
    cur_step = 0
    for _, batch in enumerate(InfiniteIterator(trainloader)):
        batch = move_to_cuda(batch, device=device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        logits = model(batch)

        batch["labels"] = label2onehot(batch["labels"], cls_number=configs.num_labels)
        losses = my_loss(logits, batch["labels"])

        loss = losses.mean()
        loss.backward()

        zero_none_grad(model)
        if configs.grad_norm != -1:
            grad_norm = clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), configs.grad_norm)

        cur_epoch = int(1. * total_bs * cur_step / len(trainloader))
        optimizer, lr_trans, lr_cnn = update_optimizer(optimizer, cur_step, cur_epoch, configs)
        optimizer.step()

        """ validation """
        if cur_step % configs.val_steps == 0 and cur_step != 0:
            print("====> GPU{} !!!!!!!! Entering testing phase !!!!!!!".format(envs['RANK']))
            dist.barrier()  # This is where the timeout occurs
            test_rst = test(model, test_loader, cur_step, envs, configs, device)
            if _global_rank == 0:
                save_model(cur_step, model.module, configs.output_dir, _global_rank)
            dist.barrier()
            
        cur_step += 1
        if cur_step >= configs.total_steps:
            break
```

The error occurs before the test fuction:

```
====> GPU5 !!!!!!!! Entering testing phase !!!!!!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "youku_cls.py", line 273, in <module>
    main(configs)
  File "youku_cls.py", line 201, in main
    dist.barrier()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py", line 2427, in barrier
    work.wait()
RuntimeError: [Rank 5] Caught collective operation timeout: WorkNCCL(OpType=ALLREDUCE, TensorShape=[1], Timeout(ms)=900000) ran for 900319 milliseconds before timing out.
====> GPU4 !!!!!!!! Entering testing phase !!!!!!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "youku_cls.py", line 273, in <module>
    main(configs)
  File "youku_cls.py", line 201, in main
    dist.barrier()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py", line 2427, in barrier
    work.wait()
RuntimeError: [Rank 4] Caught collective operation timeout: WorkNCCL(OpType=ALLREDUCE, TensorShape=[1], Timeout(ms)=900000) ran for 900629 milliseconds before timing out.
====> GPU0 !!!!!!!! Entering testing phase !!!!!!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "youku_cls.py", line 273, in <module>
    main(configs)
  File "youku_cls.py", line 201, in main
    dist.barrier()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py", line 2427, in barrier
    work.wait()
RuntimeError: [Rank 0] Caught collective operation timeout: WorkNCCL(OpType=ALLREDUCE, TensorShape=[1], Timeout(ms)=900000) ran for 900975 milliseconds before timing out.
====> GPU6 !!!!!!!! Entering testing phase !!!!!!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "youku_cls.py", line 273, in <module>
    main(configs)
  File "youku_cls.py", line 201, in main
    dist.barrier()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py", line 2427, in barrier
    work.wait()
RuntimeError: [Rank 6] Caught collective operation timeout: WorkNCCL(OpType=ALLREDUCE, TensorShape=[1], Timeout(ms)=900000) ran for 901022 milliseconds before timing out.
```

I use 8 GPUs to run the code, but there are only 4 logging

```
====> GPUX !!!!!!!! Entering testing phase !!!!!!!
```

So I figure the other 4 gpus didn't reach the test part.
I wonder why this can happen since all 8 gpus should've synced at every backward step.

Comment: Turns out it's the statement `if cur_step % configs.val_steps == 0` that causes the problem.
The size of dataloader differs slightly for different GPUs, leading to different `configs.val_steps` for different GPUs. So some GPUs jump into the `if` statement while others don't.

Unify `configs.val_steps` for all GPUs, and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know which GPUs are connected through NVLink? You may need to setup your code with this information. Also PyTorch's nn.Parallel API [says](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/v1.7.0/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py#L235) that you should use spawn for multi-processing.